# Output error using OOP

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm having trouble finding the error in my code. I'm working with the class ColHe which is a collection of objects of type Header, and the main goal is to read a file's header and obtain a list with it's elements.

This is my Header class:

```
class Header:
    def __init__(self, col):
        self._day = 'Day:'
        self._date = col[1]
        self._time = 'Time:'
        self._hours = col[3]
        self._company = 'Company:'
        self._name = 'NSHF'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._day + self._date + ", " + self._time + self._hours
                     + ", " + self._company + self._name)
```

Along with its methods of getters and setters. And this is my `ColHe` class:

```
from collections import UserList
from copy import deepcopy
import constants
from Header import Header

class ColHe(UserList):
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        super().__init__()
        in_file=open(file_name)
        for i in range(constants.HEADER):
                self.append(Header((in_file.readline().strip())))
        in_file.close()

    def getData(self):
        return deepcopy(self)

    def __str__(self):
        st = ""
        for he in self:
            st+=str(he)
        return st
```

Where constants.Header equals 6.
I ran the program with:

```
a=ColHe("file.txt")
print(a.getData())
```

And got this as an output:

```
Day:a, Time::, Company:NSHFDay:6, Time:1, Company:NSHFDay:i, Time:e, Company:NSHFDay:4, Time:5, Company:NSHFDay:o, Time:p, Company:NSHFDay:S, Time:F, Company:NSHF
```

However, the output I'm looking for looks more like this:

```
["Day:", self._date, "Time:", self._time, "Company:", "NSHF"]
```

An example of the content of a file would be:

```
Day:
06:11:2017
Time:
14:55
Company:
NSHF
```

Comment: When you'll run the code you posted there will be no output in the first place. Please post the actual code.

Comment: @ForceBru I run the code creating an ColHe object with a file name as an input and then print the result

Comment: @Inês:  It is very hard to help with a question like this if we cannot run the code ourselves.  Please provide a simple sample file, and the exact instructions or running your code so we can verify your output, and offer help.

Comment: @EthanFurman I edited my question for better understanding, I hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

When you print something in python, you don't print the *name* you have it stored under, you print its *value*.  IE:

```
print(self._date) # print whatever is stored in _date
print("self._date") # print the static string 'self._date'
```

There's no *reasonable* way to get to your desired output from your demonstrated input.  You're misunderstanding core concepts about what values are, where they are stored, and what happens when you reference them.

Answer (score 0):

Use str.format (or f-strings if your code is python 3.6+ only)

```
def __str__(self):
    return 'Day:\n{self._day}\nTime:\n{self._time}\nCompany:\n{self._company}'.format(self=self)
```

Comment: This is the general method of creating pretty printing output when you convert a class instance to a string. But I don't really understand what you are trying to do with those classes, so you also have to make sure the object actually has those attributes.